# How to get current "set" variables

Tags: bash, shell

My question is best explained with an example.

set -x or set -v "turn on" features

set +x or set +v "turn off" features

But if my script calls another script or shell function, in that other script/function, how do I get the status of these settings.  e.g.,

```
    # In called script/function
    # <save status of "set">

    set -abcdef 

    # do stuff

    # <restore status of "set">
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `$-` parameter contains a set of single-letter option flags (try `echo $-`; it produced `himBH` for me).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simple solution:

```
# In called script/function
(
  set -abcdef 
  # do stuff
)
```

The `(...)` is a subshell; when that subshell finishes, its environment dies with it, and you're back to the environment at entry.

If that's too drastic, you can make a copy of `$-` or `$SHELLOPTS` to keep the current options (`SHELLOPTS` includes some options which don't have single character abbreviations, so it is more general), and then laboriously restore from that.

Comment: Might make sense to mention `set +o` and `shopt -p` to make the restore case slightly less laborios... unless you know of reasons those don't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, all variables set in `(` subshell `)` will also be lost. It does not fit source-able scripts.